# Как добавить Graph из networkx в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, networkx

Я пытаюсь добавить в tkinker созданный заранее граф с помощью networkx, но я не знаю как добавить его в какое-нибудь поле внутри приложения.

```
def Tkinter():
    window.title("Название дам потом")
    mainmenu = Menu(window)
    window.config(menu=mainmenu)
    window.geometry('1080x800')
    window.focus_set()
    filemenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=1)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Открыть")
    filemenu.add_command(label="Создать граф", command=CreateGraph)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Обновить данные",command=Update)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Новый",command=createNewWindow)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Сохранить...")
    helpmenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="Помощь")
    helpmenu.add_command(label="О программе")
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Файл",
                         menu=filemenu)
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Справка",
                         menu=helpmenu)
    window.mainloop()


def CreateGraph():
    with open("Data.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:  # Чтение из файла название вершин и рёбер
        data = [line.split() for line in f]
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(data)
    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    nx.draw(G, pos, node_size=60, font_size=8, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Сохраните граф, как картинку в формате, который  поддерживается tkinter, допустим в .png.
   https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#formats
2. Разместите полученную картинку на холсте Canvas tkinter.